# How long can Vibrio cholerae live in its ambiental optimal context?

Tags: microbiology

How long can the *Vibrio cholerae* live in its ambiental optimal context?

Thank you in advance. My problem is that i can't find this information. I did some research on google, but nothing was retrieved, I even used other search engines. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I Found It!!!!    SURVIVAL OUTSIDE HOST: Cholera can survive in well water for 7.5 ± 1.9 days and the El Tor biotype can survive 19.3 ± 5.1 days(Footnote 21). The bacterium can survive in a wide variety of foods and drinks for 1-14 days at room temperature and 1-35 days in an ice box(Footnote 21). It has also been found on fomites at room temperature for 1-7 days(Footnote 21).

Source>>http://www.phac-aspc.gc.ca/lab-bio/res/psds-ftss/vibrio-cholerae-eng.php